# Delete a dimension in a array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to delete a dimension in a array (only if it's empty), it's pretty dificult to explain with words, so that's what i want to do :

I have an array that returns :

```
(
    [region1] => Array
        (
            [] => Array
                (
                    [0] => citie1
                    [1] => citie2

        )

    [region2] => Array
        (
            [] => Array
                (
                    [0] => citie1
                    [1] => citie2
                    [2] => citie3
                )

        )
)
```

I want it to be :

```
(
    [region1] => Array
        (
            [0] => citie1
            [1] => citie2

        )

    [region2] => Array
        (
            [0] => citie1
            [1] => citie2
            [2] => citie3

        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = reset($value);
}
```

That will replace each value in the outer array with the first element of that value.

Comment: you sure, that this code converts first OP array to necessary array ? Please, show example